# How do I set up schema for a song with multiple artist?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am creating an application to display new music. On the landing page there will be a section that displays the most recently uploaded music. When a user clicks on the song, it will take them to a show template which will display Artist name, title, video, description and artist(s) social medias.

I also want a section that displays all artist included in that song. When a user clicks an artist name it will render a page with all songs that artist has. So I am having an issue creating a schema since one song can have multiple artist.

My old schema was designed to take input from a form and displayed it without any relationships to the artist.

With my new schemas I am trying to create relationships between the artist(s) and song.

Old Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  title: String,
  image: String,
  content: String,
  description: String,
  category: String,
  soundcloud: String,
  scName: String,
  instagram: String,
  igName: String,
  twitter: String,
  twName: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Artist", artistSchema);
```

New Schemas

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  social: schema.ObjectId,
  music: schema.ObjectId
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Artist", artistSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

socialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  soundcloud: String,
  scName: String,
  instagram: String,
  igName: String,
  twitter: String,
  twName: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Social", socialSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

musicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  content: String,
  description: String,
  category: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Music", musicSchema);
```

After looking around for a while I found some documentation related to what I am trying to do. https://gist.github.com/fwielstra/1025038

So my question is if my schema is set up properly and if I will run into any problems if I continue following the Github documentation.

Answer (score 0):

look into, one to many relationship. one song relates to many artists.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

musicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  content: String,
  description: String,
  category: String,
  artists: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Users"
    }
  ]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Music", musicSchema);


voters: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "someModel[artists model]"
    }
]
```